# Use CMD or similar to open simulation software (CLI window - with its own input language) and then proceed to write input in the software DOS window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have searched the site for answer concerning my problem but haven't found anything yet that works.

I am using a software for numerical simulations. The software is proprietary, has it's own graphical user interface and also the option to input commands with its CLI window. The software allows to write text files for its own programming language that can then be called via the CLI window or the GUI and executed. The programming language is very limited and (for example) does not allow the execution of a certain model setup multiple times with only slightly modified input parameters (unless the whole code for a model is written out repeatedly in one file or similar.

Therefore, I want to call the program (by running the respective .exe file in CMD) and the use some sort of stdin, stdout to make my script write the commands I want into the CLI window of the software.

1) Open cmd

2) open software "path\to\executable*.exe"

3) wait until software window is up

4) write commands for software to execute (e.g. go/to/certain/folder - /run/certain/file)

What would be the easiest way? I tried some things with java and eclipse, but didn't manage to get it to run.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AutoIt` script can help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried that. I wrote a file opening up the DOS window of my program but seem unable to parse the input that the DOS window should get afterwards. Any hints???

Comment: EDIT: I got stuff to work with AutiIT. Thanks a lot for the tip. Now it only doesn't work if I click on other programs while the code is running.